Trying to set custom 404 error page on nginx
I want to use my custom error page for returning 404 errors so I've tried every instruction on the internet for that but none of them worked I wonder if Nginx's latest versions still support this and if so how can I configure that?
Please help me
This is /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf file:
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name "";
    return      444;
}
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        return 404;
      root /var/www/html;
       server_name _;
        return 404;

        location / {

                error_page 404 403 /404.html;
                location /404.html {
                        internal;
                        allow all;
                }
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
   }
}


You have two return 404 statements in your server block. Those will break your website. And Nginx will not be able to process your error_page anyway.
Also, you have nested your location blocks for no good reason.
Try:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    error_page 404 403 /404.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }
}


The a default_server, the server_name is optional.
error_page should be moved to the server context, unless you have a good reason to set it for a specific location.
allow all is unneccesary unless there is a deny somewhere.
location /404.html will also work, but location = /404.html is more specific.


This is how I reconfigured the default.conf file
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
return 404;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
error_page 404 403 /404.html;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location = /404.html {
    internal;
}

}
However, the browser still keeps showing the default Nginx 404 error page.
I wonder if is it possible to change the default error page for external requests?

Yes. That configuration in your comment will show the default 404 page. You can ignore everything after the return 404. The configuration in your comment tells Nginx to listen on port 80 and return default 404 response to any request. Move or delete the return statement if you want it to work correctly.

Thanks, that worked for me after removing return 404.
